# How do I mock an ES6 module in only a single test in Jest?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs, es6-modules

Say I have the following module:

**src/validators.js**

```
export const isPositiveNumber = value => value > 0 && value < Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER;
```

I use it in another module:

**src/calculators/volume.js**

```
import { isPositiveNumber } from '../validators';
import { InvalidArgumentException } from '../exceptions';

export const sphere = radius => {
    if (!isPositiveNumber(radius)) {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException('radius must be a positive number');
    }

    return (4/3) * Math.PI * Math.pow(radius, 3);
};
```

Then in my test:

**tests/calculators/volume.test.js**

```
import { volume } from '../../src/calculators/volume';
import { InvalidArgumentException } from '../../src/exceptions';
import { isPositiveNumber } from '../../src/validators';

jest.mock('../../src/validators');

describe('Volume calculations', () => {
    describe('sphere()', () => {
        it('should throw an exception if the radius is invalid', () => {
            isPositiveNumber.mockReturnValue(false);
            expect(() => volume()).toThrow(InvalidArgumentException);
        });

        it('should compute the volume', () => {
            isPositiveNumber.mockReturnValue(true);
            expect(volume(3)).toBeCloseTo(113,3);
        });
    });
});
```

This works, EXCEPT, I don't want to have mock `isPositiveNumber` in the second test that actually computes the volume.

I want the `isPositiveNumber` mock to be ONLY in the validation test.

I do not know how to do this given the ES6 module setup I'm using. It seems to require the mock interception happen outside of the scope of the test, which means I have to mock the return value in EVERY test in the suite.

This is just an example of a simple test, but there will be more complex tests later, and I want to know how to more precisely mock ES6 modules on a per-test basis.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

That's probably because you're using `babel-jest`, which [according to the documentation](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/jest-object.html#jestdomockmodulename-factory-options), will hoist `jest.mock()` to top-level regardless of where it's actually placed in your ES6 module code.

> When using `babel-jest`, calls to `mock` will automatically be hoisted to the top of the code block.

Instead, you can use the [`jest.doMock()`](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/jest-object.html#jestdomockmodulename-factory-options) and [`jest.dontMock()`](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/jest-object.html#jestdontmockmodulename) methods in your `before()` and `after()` hooks respectively for individual tests that require you to mock the functions in your module definition.

Comment: We have an alternative to `jest.spyOn` too?

Comment: @DouglasNassifRomaJunior there's no object with a method name to spy on.